Probability using Stars and Bars
This is a problem from Blitzstein Hwang Intro to Probability.
A survey is being conducted in a city with 1 million residents. It would be far too expensive to survey all of the residents, so a random sample of size 1000 is chosen (in practice, there are many challenges with sampling, such as obtaining a complete list of everyone in the city, and dealing with people who refuse to participate). The survey is conducted by choosing people one at a time, with replacement and with equal probabilities.
(a) Explain how sampling with vs. without replacement here relates to the birthday problem.
(b) Find the probability that at least one person will get chosen more than once.
If the problem instead asked for b) without choosing people one at a time, with replacement and with equal probabilities. Can you use stars and bars?
The total number of ways to pick 1000 people with replacement and without ordering is ${10^6 + 10^3 - 1 \choose 10^3}.$ The total number of ways to pick 1000 people without replacement (that is at most 1) is ${10^6 \choose 10^3}.$
So would the answer would be $1-\frac{{10^6\choose 10^3}}{{10^6+10^3-1\choose 10^3}}.$

Stars and bars is almost always incorrect to use in the context of probability, particularly as the size of a sample space.

Yes, but in this case  isn't it symmetric?

Ratio of counts of sets being interpreted as a probability is only valid when it is known that the outcomes being counted are equally likely to have occurred.  By using stars-and-bars here you are tacitly assuming that the outcome where John Smith is chosen 1000 times is equally likely to the outcome where the first thousand people in the phonebook are chosen in some order... but in practice, those thousand people could have been chosen in $1000!$ different orders while still qualifying as ""the first thousand people in the phonebook were chosen*" and so is far far more likely an event.

Ok! So in general - never use stars and bars in probability.

Unless it is very explicitly stated that the different outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are what are being sampled from uniformly at random... correct.  There do also exist valid circumstances where the numerator can be counted using stars-and-bars, but as a general rule of thumb... you should assume stars-and-bars will never ever be used in a denominator as a rule and recognize any exceptions to this as an extreme special case that makes it clear why it is an exception.

Sounds good, thanks!!
